# FaiServer 5.3.6 on Ubuntu 20.04: live-boot no supported filesystem images found at /live. (initramfs)

Tags: boot, initramfs, pxe

I'm trying to upgrade my **FAIserver** env from jessie (FAI-Server 4.3.1+deb8u1) to focal (FAI-Server 5.3.6ubuntu1)

on the old system (Jessie) I generate **nfsroot** with the command:

```
fai-make-nfsroot -glfv
```

but on the new FAI-Server release the option **"-l"** was removed and I generate my nfsroot with the command:

```
fai-make-nfsroot -gfv
```

but when I try to boot my client I receive this error:

> live-boot will now start a shell. The error message was:
> No supported filesystem images found at /live

this is my pxe file:

```
MENU LABEL ^FAI build (gfx_console)
            kernel vmlinuz-5.4.0-104-generic
            append initrd=initrd.img-5.4.0-104-generic ethdevice-timeout=30 ip=dhcp root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=/fai/nfsroot/focal boot=live FAI_FLAGS=verbose,sshd,createvt FAI_ACTION=install SERVER=192.168.1.100 FAI_CONFIG_SRC=nfs://192.168.1.100/fai/config-focal/ console=ttyS0,9600n8 console=tty0
```

This is my **NFSROOT** file:

```
PACKAGES aptitude
nfs-common fai-nfsroot ssh rdate lshw rpcbind
rsync lftp less dump reiserfsprogs e2fsprogs usbutils
hwinfo psmisc pciutils hdparm smartmontools parted mdadm lvm2
dnsutils ntpdate dosfstools xfsprogs xfsdump
procinfo numactl dialog
console-common
udev subversion
xz-utils
cupt
sysvinit sysvinit-utils
systemd-
moreutils
module-init-tools console-tools iproute
kbd iproute2
firmware-bnx2 firmware-bnx2x firmware-realtek
live-boot live-boot-initramfs-tools
initramfs-tools
vim nano
htop 
PACKAGES aptitude I386
grub-pc read-edid
linux-image-686
linux-image-generic
PACKAGES aptitude AMD64
grub-pc
linux-image-amd64
linux-image-generic
```

What can I check to fix it?

Comment: Hello. You may want to inquire at the official support for that product. https://fai-project.org/

Comment: I asked, but without answer